# how to update the telerik theme version in c#, visual studio

Tags: c#, telerik, version

I created a project 3 months ago which uses telerik UI and migrations in c#, and after that i reinstall the visual studio setup, so now i install the entity framework and telerik, my UI is showing now, but when i run the project it gives me this error.

```
Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression StateError  CS1705  Assembly
 'Telerik.WinControls.Themes.TelerikMetroBlue'
 with identity 'Telerik.WinControls.Themes.TelerikMetroBlue, Version=2020.1.218.40, Culture=neutral,
 PublicKeyToken=5bb2a467cbec794e' uses 
'Telerik.WinControls, Version=2020.1.218.40, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=5bb2a467cbec794e' which has a higher version than 
referenced assembly 'Telerik.WinControls' with identity 'Telerik.WinControls, Version=2012.1.321.20, 
Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=5bb2a467cbec794e'
```

which says the version of  Telerik.WinControls.Themes.TelerikMetroBlue is 2020.1.218.40 but Telerik.WinControls version is 2012.1.321.20. i am trying to update it now but couldn't find the solution.

here is the snap of the error

[image]

please help me how to fix this issue.

Comment: Have you tried removing all references to `Telerik.WinControls` from the project and then reinstall?

Comment: no, where to remove references?

Comment: should i need to delete the bin folder?